# Is there an Infix phrase for "any of x are y" in the english language?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, quantifiers

For a collection of objects x and predicate y, you can say "all of x are y". For example, "It is probably summer if *all of* the Tree's leaves *are* green". But you can also say "x are all y", for example "It is probably summer if the tree's leaves *are all* green." The latter is what I mean by "infix".

Similarly, for a collection of objects x and predicate y, you can say "any of x are y". For example, you can say "It probably isn't winter if *any of* the tree's leaves *are* green".

However I can't think of a similar infix version of this second phrase. That is, I can't think of anything like "x are any y" that sounds right or makes sense, e.g.  "It probably isn't winter if the tree's leaves are any green"  sounds like nonsense.

Is there an infix version of this phrase in the english language?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Welcome. Nice question but it needs to be re-worded. You have leaves being green in winter. Not likely. Please choose some other example, there must be many, to explore the idea. Then an answer will streak across the sky for us.

Comment: Partly green perhaps. There is also the distinction between all the leaves have a green colour and every leaf is coloured all in green. BTW many Australian trees are green through winter and new growth in spring is reddish.

Comment: @Elliot I think there is a confusion somewhere. "I said it probably *isn't* winter if any of the tree's leaves are green".

Comment: In Texas many leaves remain green during the Winter. A clearer example should be easy to build.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have commented, rather than answered, but I don't have that privilege. So, a suggestion:

If you accept "…if the tree's leaves **are all** green" for "x are all y", then you could say ‘...if the tree's leaves **are at all** green'.

Of course, this might pertain to how many of the leaves are green, but also to the extent to which the leaves are green (more or less), and 'at all' doesn't quite mean 'any'...

Comment: I understand the suggestion so I commend it. We might also go for the circumlocution “... are showing green”